# Waiting at Frankfurt Airport Before Check-in

Tags: fra, airport-terminals

We are travelling abroad from Frankfurt airport. Our flight is at night 9 pm. But we plan to reach the airport by evening (3 pm), way before the 3 hours check-in time. 
So is there a warm place where we can sit before the check-in starts?

We will reach Frankfurt airport by ICE train.

Comment: It's a good question - what specifically is there at Frankfurt airport, BEFORE check-in?  I don't know or remember.

Comment: One trick (in general, for "many" airports) is to go to the *arrivals* area, as if you're meeting someone, not departures.  There are usually shops/etc there, for the people waiting to meet someone arriving. Many airports indeed *have little or nothing at all* literally "before checkin".

Comment: @JoeBlow Great tip on the *arrival* thingy! Would keep this in mind now on.

Comment: It sounds like you'll have no problems at Frankfurt, based on the other dude's comments!  I've used FRA many times (the hotel in the airport, Hilton I think, is fantastic) - shows you how drunk I am that I can't remember if there are shops or not  :O

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don’t know why you would want to be at the airport six hours before you flight departs, but maybe you have bad experiences with long-distance trains or the connection was simply so much better or something. In any case, the most obvious solution for ‘some place warm’ is simply to go into the airport itself.

Since it is the largest airport in Germany and one of the largest in Europe with flights all day round (except for the night hours) you can always just enter the building. There are shops and cafés landside. Maybe you can even check in that early, especially if your flight is with one of the major airlines (e.g. Lufthansa), which would allow you to enter the airside area where there are more shops and cafés.

Comment: Thanks for the information! I really want to be safe as DB trains are late often.

Comment: @Jeet.Deir This is outside of what you asked but if your train is more than 60 minutes late remember to claim compensation. 60 minutes delay at your final station equates to 25 % refund, 120 minutes to a 50 % refund. But travelling a lot with DB I cannot agree with ‘trains are often late’, especially not *that* late ;).

Comment: Maybe I had bad experience! twice I had important meetings cancelled for the same so maybe I am a bit skeptic. But thanks anyway for the information.

Comment: I agree that I would arrive 6hrs early, if DB is involved!

Comment: "There are shops and cafés landside" are you quite sure there are "shops and cafes" actually BEFORE checkin?

Comment: There's a whole little [mall](http://www.frankfurt-airport.com/en/flights---more/transfer.detail.suffix.html/glossary/glossary-standard/a/airport-city-mall.html) area presecurity with, per that page, 27 shops, snacks, and services.

Comment: @JoeBlow Even smaller airports have cafés and shops before check-in.

Comment: @JoeBlow: FRA is huge. There is a full mall in Terminal 2. There is a real supermarket under Terminal 1/A. Tons of smaller shops and dining. All landside. The airport has about 200-ish shops, stalls and eateries and about 25% of those are landside.

Comment: @Hilmar - fantastic.  And you DON'T have to pass checkin to get to that part of the landside?

Comment: @JoeBlow No, you DON'T. See the link in Zach Lipton's comment above: "The Airport City Mall is in the publicly accessible (presecurity) part of Terminal 1 next to the regional train station. It features numerous retail outlets, restaurants, and services for passengers and visitors to take advantage of."